# Getting beacon message when triggered

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

In my application I need to detect iBeacon when button is pressed on it, not when the device is in range. Currently I am using
[Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html).

With this library I can see beacon and know what the current range is, but I cannot handle any event or see anything when a user clicks on a button on iBeacon device. Is there some way to detect it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you accomplish your goal all depends on what the beacon dies differently when you click on it.  Understand that a standard iBeacon doesn't have a button, so the manufacturer must have added some proprietary mechanism to do something when the button us pressed.  The question is: what does the button do?

Knowing the answer to this will likely allow you to program a solution.  I'd suggest looking for documentation from the manufacturer on what the beacon does when the button is pressed.